# Question with the same title exists

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, title

Today I was surprised (next time) when I tried to remove a Tag from a title - I got an exception *You cannot do it - question with the same title exists.* (Yeah something similar, but the meaning stays the same).

And I think - from one side it is said that [Questions shouldn't include Tags in their title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) and *good question* means short, understandible title. As my experience shows - the OP can be 'forced' to include the Tag, because the SO won't accept the question with short title as it already exists.

SO every day is getting more and more questions and simple, short titles are *runnig out*.

Can something be done with that limitation? I know that I can just add some spaces after the title and it will be accepted, but of course after some time Titles with additional spaces will also run out... ;)

[Here - is an example of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23570358/2681948) I've edited just before this post - I couldn't add simple title *Animation not working*, I had to add a space.

Comment: Can you link the question you tried to edit?

Comment: Probably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498187/display-local-toast-notification).

Comment: This should be a big red flag that the title either doesn't describe the problem effectively, or that the other question is a duplicate.

Comment: @AmalMurali This could be probably the second example.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, but for example 'Animation not working' IMO is not a very bad title, and there probably may be many different reasons why the animation isn't working, they won't be duplicate questions.

Comment: That *is* a fairly poor title.  It doesn't tell me much at all about what's going on precisely because there are so many types of different questions that correspond to it.

Comment: @Servy As I think now - I agree - having 100 questions 'Animation not working' wouldn't be good. I must rethink my way of editing titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's already a question with exact same title, chances are:

- This question is a duplicate
- The title of this question is way too general and doesn't describe the problem accurately

If it's the first case, then close this question as a dupe of the  other one. The question you linked had this title originally: "Animation not working in Windows Phone 8.1". This title wasn't particularly great, but it managed to describe the problem to an extent.

By removing the tag from the title (in this case), you're removing the context. The current title reads: "Animation not working". To someone reading just the title, this would be confusing. *What animation? Not working how?* It's not a good title, IMO.

I'd have personally left the title  as it was. Your primary objective is not to find a title that passes the "duplicate title" test, but to find a title that *actually* describes the problem. It isn't always possible, but in most cases, the title can be edited out to be not too vague.

A bad title (from the [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/220538)):

> JavaScript, jQuery: When should I use one or the other?

A good title:

> Can I use jQuery to foo the bar on the baz, or am I stuck using plain JavaScript?

As you can see, the second title is *much* more readable and describes the problem well. There's no need to remove the tag from the title if the tag syncs with the title nicely.

Comment: Good points. I must agree that the previous title was better - having many questions with so short simple title can be worse that having them with their tags.