# Similar questions, in a different technology even though I tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, related-questions

While I was asking [this question, about Android and layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079841/android-layout-place-a-view-between-two-views), and after I tagged accordingly, under "Questions that may already have your answer" appeared suggestions that are meant for iOS:

[image: Question 1]

[[link for marked question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334016/auto-layout-and-centering-a-view-in-between-two-other-views)

[image: Question 2]

[[link for marked question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532056/auto-layout-create-constraint-between-two-views-in-separate-windows)

And also one for SQL:

[image: Question 3]

[[link for marked question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830030/creating-a-view-between-two-tables-in-sql)

The tags:

[image: Tags]

The 2nd and 3rd questions are tagged with [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql); two totally different technologies, which aren't in the new question's tags or title. The 1st one would be more difficult to differentiate, because its tags don't contain a technology, but wouldn't it be "easy" to tell that the 2nd and 3rd are clearly not similar to the new question at all?

Comment: Related: [Question with the same title exists](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254233/3853934)

Comment: There are several different kinds of tags that are on one question and not on another. Some, like [tag:ios], constrain the basic problem domain and are almost always exclusive of other tags that do the same thing. Some, like [tag:c#], *can* constrain the problem domain, but only do so some of the time (there are C# questions that cannot be translated to VB, but often it's just tweaking some surface syntax). And then there are cases like [tag:array] that are really just adding descriptions. How do you propose the software should distinguish between these? (Bonus: How about other sites?)